Does steric hindrance affect the enantiomer ratio in a reaction?
Interestingly, the authors synthesized four substituted cyclophanes (7q, 7r, 7s, and 7t) that show planar chirality, and the enantiomers (Rp and Sp) are present in a 1:1 molar ratio.
It's fascinating that the same molar ratio is observed for all substituted cyclophanes.

I had anticipated that steric hindrance would have an effect. Shouldn't the size of the substituents affect the enantiomer ratio? In other words, does steric hindrance affect the enantiomer ratio in a reaction?
This is the proposed mechanism

